# Converting ArrayLists to arrays

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I wanted to know if it was possible to change

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>
```

to String[][] in java. I do not think that the toArray() function would recurse inside its generic parameter. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that toArray won't recurse. I'm afraid you'll have to do this manually. Something like:

```
List<List<String>> stringLists;
String[][] stringArrays = new String[stringLists.size()][];
int i = 0;
foreach (List<String> stringList: stringLists) {
    stringArrays[i] = stringList.toArray(new String[stringList.size()]);
    ++i;
}
```

I haven't actually tried that, mind, so it could be rubbish.

Comment: you get it, 3 secs before me :)

Comment: I got lucky - my typing is usually so bad it takes me another minute to get my posts fixed before i can post them, but today it came out quite quickly!

Comment: I was gonna ask how you typed and formatted it so fast ;) Do you usually use eclipse to answer ? I type directly in the textfield and correct indentation manually.

Comment: No, i just type in the text area. I am a pretty fast typist, but i'm generally quite inaccurate, so although i can type something fast, i then need to spend as much time fixing it as i spent typing it. This time, i didn't make as many mistakes as usual.

Answer (score 0):

if bigL is your bigger array list, and tab has been created to bigL.size().

Can't you do something like :

```
for( ArrayList<String> l : bigL )
{
  tab[ index ++ ] = l.toArray( new String[ l.size() ] );
}//for
```